# MySQL error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

When trying to create the trigger below, I get this message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; END' at line 9
```

Can someone please help?  Thank you

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_item_status
AFTER UPDATE ON check_in 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.quantity > 0 AND NEW.quantity <= 0 THEN
    UPDATE check_in SET item_status = 'Sold';
  ELSEIF OLD.quantity <= 0 AND NEW.quantity > 0 THEN
    UPDATE check_in SET item_status = 'Available';
  ENDIF;
END;$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: There is something wrong. The UPDATE commands will update EVERY ROW WITH SAME item_status. My answer will update only the row in question. Please test this out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_item_status
AFTER UPDATE ON check_in  
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.quantity > 0 AND NEW.quantity <= 0 THEN
    UPDATE check_in SET item_status = 'Sold';
  ELSEIF OLD.quantity <= 0 AND NEW.quantity > 0 THEN
    UPDATE check_in SET item_status = 'Available';
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This should work. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_item_status
BEFORE UPDATE ON check_in 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.quantity > 0 AND NEW.quantity <= 0 THEN
    SET NEW.item_status = 'Sold';
  ELSEIF OLD.quantity <= 0 AND NEW.quantity > 0 THEN
    SET NEW.item_status = 'Available';
  END IF;
END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Three(3) things:

- The ENDIF; should be END IF;
- This should be a BEFORE UPDATE trigger because data validation is better before any table operation
- The UPDATE statements are semantically wrong. I changed them to set the NEW column name instead

Comment: I tried to get rid of ; after END, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Thanks Rolando.  ENDIF is the problem.